# JSON data from php not outputting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am running into an issue getting JSON data that is sent from a php file to output onto my page. What I am trying to do is create a commenting system, so whenever someone makes a comment, my AJAX code gets the SELECT query results and reloads the already listed comments, essentially to show new comments, whether the user posted it or someone else did.

What I have is three files, the comments page, AJAX, and PHP files. I do a `SELECT` query initially on the comments page to get the data on page load, then I want the same set of comments to consistently load every three seconds.

The `setInterval()` is working and the JSON is being sent over, as I see it within my console, but it isn't actually refreshing and outputting. In addition, I really only want the comments to reload if there has been a new comment created, rather than the comments reloading just to reload.

Does anyone seeing what I am doing wrong for the JSON data to not output?

Here is how I initially get the output on the page load. This is solely using the php on the comments page.

```
<div id="comment-container">
<?php
$select_comments_sql = "
    SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
    FROM home_comments AS c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                FROM profile_img 
                GROUP BY user_id) PI
      on PI.user_id = c.user_id
    INNER JOIN profile_img p
      on PI.user_id = p.user_id
     and PI.id = p.id
    ORDER BY c.id DESC
";

  if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
        $select_comments_stmt->execute();
        if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
            //echo "error";
        }
        $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date, $commenter_user_id, $commenter_img);
    //var_dump($select_comments_stmt);  
        $comment_array = array();
        while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
            $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
            $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_date;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_img;
            $commenter_img = '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src=" '.$commenter_img.'">';
            if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                echo 'No comments found.';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="comment-post-box" id="comment-'. $comment_id .'">';
                //echo '<div class="comment-post-box" id="comment-'.$row['id'].'">';
                echo $commenter_img;
                echo '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                echo '<div>'.$comment_date. '</div>';
                echo '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
  }
?>
        </div>
```

The PHP to SELECT from the home_comments table and echos the JSON

```
$user = new User();

        //Get the last insert id
            $select_comments_sql = "
            SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
            FROM home_comments AS c
            INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                        FROM profile_img 
                        GROUP BY user_id) PI
              on PI.user_id = c.user_id
            INNER JOIN profile_img p
              on PI.user_id = p.user_id
             and PI.id = p.id
            ORDER BY c.id DESC
        ";

        if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
            //$select_comments_stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $select_comments_stmt->execute();
            $rows = $select_comments_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $comments = array();
            foreach ($rows as $row) {

                    $html = "";
                    //$html .= '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                    $html .= '<div class="comment-post-box" id="comment-'.$row['id'].'">';
                    $html .= '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src="'.$row['img'].'">';
                    $html .= '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$row['username']. '</div>';
                    $html .= '<div>'.$row['date']. '</div>';
                    $html .= '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$row['comment']. '</div>';
                    $html .= '</div>';
                    $data = array('id' => $row['id'], 'date' => $row['date'], 'html' => $html);
                    $comments[] = $data;
            }
        }
                echo json_encode($comments);
```

Then my AJAX to attempt to refresh the list of comments:

```
function commentRetrieve(){

    $.ajax({ 
            url: "ajax-php/comment-retrieve.php",
            type: "get",
            success: function (data) {
              //console.log(data);
                if (data == "Error!") {
                    alert("Unable to retrieve comment!");
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    var array = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(data);
                    $(array).each(function(this) {
                        if($('#comment-' + this.id).length == 0) {
                            $('#comment-container').prepend(this.html);
                            console.log(this.html);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
            }
        });


}
setInterval(commentRetrieve, 3000);
```

Edit: DATA sent over

```
[{id: "51", date: "2016-10-26 09:25:42",…}, {id: "22", date: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",…},…]
0
:
{id: "51", date: "2016-10-26 09:25:42",…}
1
:
{id: "22", date: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",…}
2
:
{id: "21", date: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",…}
3
:
{id: "20", date: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",…}
4
:
{id: "19", date: "2016-10-23 09:56:08",…}
5
:
{id: "18", date: "2016-10-21 09:51:35",…}
6
:
{id: "16", date: "2016-10-20 14:41:10",…}
7
:
{id: "15", date: "2016-10-20 13:23:30",…}
8
:
{id: "12", date: "2016-10-20 09:10:28",…}
9
:
{id: "11", date: "2016-10-19 23:54:58",…}
10
:
{id: "10", date: "2016-10-19 23:41:52",…}
11
:
{id: "9", date: "2016-10-19 23:41:52",…}
12
:
{id: "8", date: "2016-10-19 23:41:16",…}
```

Where I received ^^

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported?

Comment: Well, since it is JSON you're receiving you can just use it. You do not have to parse it again.

Comment: You could use the ajax `dataType: "json",`.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(data);` with `dataType: "json",` and without parsing ?

Comment: *"Edit: DATA sent over"* are you sure? where did you get that? that looks very much invalid.

Comment: I mean no do `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: @Paul You need to add the `'id="comment-'.$row['id'].'"'` to the `.comment-post-box` JSON html

Comment: IMHO, it seems correct...

Comment: @Paul Ah, then you have the data. What problem are you having then? just access it. You have an array of objects, treat it as such.

Comment: ... uhm.  yeah, that's just simple array/property access... `theArray[0]` gets the first item in the array, `theArray[1]` gets the second. `theObject.somekey` gets `somekey` from `theObject`, etc.

Comment: You're already doing this in your code though. `$.ajax` gets `ajax` from `$`.

Comment: Yes, certainly because the following function use the `array` var and is unable to find it anymore.

Comment: @AdrienLeber JSON.parse is required in this case because the server-code is not written to return the correct content-type.

Comment: probably because you're iterating over the array incorrectly, or accessing the properties of the objects incorrectly.

Comment: Carefully read the documentation for the jquery method you are using. http://api.jquery.com/each/ pay extra attention to the arguments the callback will receive.

Comment: What do you mean @KevinB ? The php script send the data as json encoded value.

Comment: @Paul Again.... You need to add the `'id="comment-'.$row['id'].'"'` to the `.comment-post-box` JSON html.  It's loading everything because your test always fails.

Comment: @AdrienLeber right, and json is a string. not a javascript object. jQuery also sees it as a string, because nothing is telling it that it is json.

Comment: @KevinB, ok I see, that's why I hint the `dataType: "json",` that validates the json format on the fly.

Comment: If you add dataType:"json", you should remove JSON.parse. and vice-versa.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the ajax request, stop changing it. Fix your .each.

Comment: @Paul in the unnamed php titled "The PHP to SELECT from the home_comments table and echos the JSON" you do not give your ".comment-post-box" `div`s an `id`.  Your selector (`'#comment-' + $value.id`) will always return an empty array and your comments will always be entirely reloaded

Comment: @KevinB They are embedded in the HTML, it's entirely relevant

Comment: @Tibrogargan i don't think he's even getting as far as appending html. `0.id` isn't going to work.

Comment: @KevinB I quote: " I am just wanting this output to update the static page when there is a new comment., **rather than seeing all of the comments load every three seconds**"

Comment: Sure, but his code, **as written**, ***won't even do that.***

Comment: @Paul this solution isn't particularly scalable by the way.  Consider sending a timestamp from the client to the server and only getting comments after the timestamp in your SQL

Comment: `if($('#comment-' + $value.id).length == 0) {` is selecting an element with an id of `comment-undefined`, it's length will always be 0

Comment: @KevinB stop nit picking.  Even if that piece would work, without the ID being set it still won't do anything.  Our comments are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Why would he want row id instead of the comment id he's already putting there?

Comment: @Paul Not sure what line you're modifying.  It should be this one: `$html .= '<div class="comment-post-box">';`.  Change it to : `$html .= '<div class="comment-post-box" id="comment-'.$row['id'].'">';`

Comment: Do I need to add something to my first block of code I put in my question? Because this is the only thing that is showing the comments now.

Comment: @KevinB How could I do this the timestamp way? I see what you mean with the `if($('#comment-' + $value.id).length == 0) {`

Comment: [$value isn't what you think it is.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269106/json-data-from-php-not-outputting?noredirect=1#comment67799064_40269106)

Comment: Isn't it just nothing right now because it isn't defined?

Comment: no, it's the current index.... read the docs!! i linked to them for you!

Comment: Yes, and I am looking at them. I didn't know that you could set the index as a function.

Comment: Yet again, `.each()`'s wierd argument ordering is the culprit.  Either use the arg or just use `this` instead of `$value`

Comment: @Tibrogargan I changed all of the `$value`'s to `$this`' and no help. I am not sure if this will help, but if either of you want to look at it to see it live, here is the link http://farleysharley.com/test-index ... username: test12 ... password : test12

Comment: @Paul to do the timestamp piece you would need to add an argument to your URL.  Something like `ajax-php/comment-retrieve.php?timestamp=XXX`.  You can get a UTC timestamp in javascript with `new Date().getTime()`.  I believe PHP can convert them into date objects easily enough.  Just add a where clause to your SQL (perhaps "where home_comments.date > *timestamp*")

Comment: Not `$this`, `this`.  Don't do the timestamp thing now.  Fix this bit first :)

Comment: How would querying for only those timestamps that are larger make the comments outout though?

Comment: I changed it to this. No luck.

Comment: @Paul update your question with your current version please.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small working example:

```js
var count = 0;
var RETRIEVE_INTERVAL = 1000;
var datas = [ '[{"id": "51", "date": "2016-10-26 09:25:42", "html": "<div id=\\"comment-51\\">51</div>"}]'
            , '[{"id": "22", "date": "2016-10-26 09:25:42", "html": "<div id=\\"comment-22\\">22</div>"}]'
            , '[{"id": "5", "date": "2016-10-26 09:25:42", "html": "<div id=\\"comment-5\\">5</div>"}]'
            , '[{"id": "34", "date": "2016-10-26 09:25:42", "html": "<div id=\\"comment-34\\">34</div>"}]'
            , '[{"id": "51", "date": "2016-10-26 09:25:42", "html": "<div id=\\"comment-51\\">51</div>"}]'
            , '[{"id": "10", "date": "2016-10-26 09:25:42", "html": "<div id=\\"comment-10\\">10</div>"}]'
            , '[{"id": "70", "date": "2016-10-26 09:25:42", "html": "<div id=\\"comment-51\\">70</div>"}]'
            , '[{"id": "22", "date": "2016-10-26 09:25:42", "html": "<div id=\\"comment-22\\">22</div>"}]'
            , '[{"id": "40", "date": "2016-10-26 09:25:42", "html": "<div id=\\"comment-40\\">40</div>"}]'
            ];

function commentRetrieve(){
    // mock data retrieval
    if (count == datas.length)
        return;
    var data = datas[count++];

    var array = JSON.parse(data);
    $(array).each(function() {
        if($('#comment-' + this.id).length == 0) {
            $('#comment-container').prepend(this.html);
        }
    });

    setInterval(commentRetrieve, RETRIEVE_INTERVAL);
}

$(commentRetrieve);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="comment-container" id="intro-box">
    <div id="comment-5">5</div>
    <div id="comment-10">10</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The thing is, I have an initial query that selects all the comments in my db and I write it in without the json data, so within comment-container there is already comments.

Comment: Doesn't matter if there are already comments there, because you're checking if they exist before you try to add new ones.

Comment: @Paul redid the example with comments already in the page.  You'll see in the "data stream" it's trying to add those same comments again

Comment: Should I add the init like you did?  I thought this sufficed? `setInterval(commentRetrieve, 3000);`

Comment: @Paul no, that was just from my test code.  Easier to leave it how you have it.

Comment: Well then what about how you are calling for it out of the function `$(commentRetrieve);`. I am setting the interval and calling for it out of the function? `setInterval(commentRetrieve, 3000);` Just trying to check every possibility. BTW, I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: the `this` change or something small before hand must have done it! It does actually work. I went into the network tab of the developer tools and turned the cache off and it started working.

Comment: Fairly sure I know who downvoted it.  It's no big deal, rep is over-rated, too many people treat it like a score in a game.  I'm calling it using the jQuery document ready facility mainly from habit, you don't need to do that ($(*function*) is an alias for $(document).ready(*function*)).  The difference between just calling setInterval() and using "document ready" is that there is a chance that the document isn't actually ready when your function is called.  Admittedly very slight here since you're using ajax

Comment: Gotcha! I am noticing it doesn't work with a user without a set profile picture... ie, this line: `$html .= '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src="'.$row['img'].'">';` is there another way I can do it, so it will check for `$row['img']` and `$default_profile_img = '<img class="welcome-pic" src="profile_images/default.jpg">';` ?

Comment: Almost certainly, but maybe you should ask a new question.  I haven't done any PHP seriously for many years, any answer would be a guess

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thanks!

Comment: Or I should say, I really appreciate ALL of the time you spent on this. I have been going at it for days. THANKS